# Apache Kafka : Processor generates multiple output per input

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka stream processor that has to take one item as input, and produces multiple item as output.
What is the right way to code it ? Are multiple calls to `this.context().forward(key, item)` the right way to do it, or is there another cheat ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For Processor API, `context.forward(key, item)` is correct.

For DSL, you could also use `KStream#flatMapValues()` or `KStream()flatMap()`.